# How to fix "aggressive loop optimization" error with threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, optimization, pthreads

I get a warning as " iteration 3 invokes undefined behavior". The task is: Create a multi-threaded program that reads an integer value n from the user (you can assume any constant) and finds the sum of numbers from 1 to n using 4 new threads, where each thread computes only ¼ of the sum. Main thread prints out the final sum.

My code is given below, thank you in advance

```
//gcc 5.4.0
#include <pthread.h> //pthread_t
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float sum[5];

void *sumf(void *arg){
    int a = *((int *) arg); 

    for(int i=1;i<=4; i++){
    sum[i] = a+a*(a/8); // Using arithmetic sequence formula to find 1/4 part of sum
    }

    free(arg);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n=4;
    int *np=&n;
    float totalsum=0;    
    pthread_t thread[4]; //declare  threads

    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, sumf, (void *)np);  
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL); //thread waits
    }

    //main thread
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        totalsum+=sum[i];
    }
    printf("%.2f", totalsum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_t thread[4]; for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)`. When `i` is `4` it will be an invalid index for `thread` array. The valid indices are 0-3. In C, array indices start from `0`. So should be `for (int i=0; i<4; i++)`

Comment: Your code may use threads, but it doesn't do anything in parallel, which kind-of defeats the purpose of using threads. Also, lots of other things are off. If you have this running, consider filing it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why do you think you need `free(arg);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_t thread[4];` - `thread` is an array of `pthread_t` which contains 4 elements.

When using:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, sumf, (void *)np);  
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL); //thread waits
}
```

the program attempts to access an element beyond the bounds of the array at the last iteration because indexing start at `0`, not `1`. Means the last element of `thread` is `thread[3]`, not `thread[4]`. You attempt to access a non-existing `thread[4]`, when `i == 4`.

---

Also when using:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    totalsum += sum[i];
}
```

You miss to use the value of the first element of `sum`, `sum[0]` to summarize the values of all elements of `sum` in `totalsum`.

Same goes for:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
     sum[i] = a + a * (a/8); // Using arithmetic sequence formula to find 1/4 part of sum
}
```

---

Change:

#### 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, sumf, (void *)np);  
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL); //thread waits
}
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, sumf, (void *)np);  
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL); //thread waits
}
```

---

#### 2.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    totalsum += sum[i];
}
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    totalsum += sum[i];
}
```

or respectively:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    totalsum += sum[i];
}
```

---

and

#### 3.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4 ; i++){
    sum[i] = a + a * (a/8); // Using arithmetic sequence formula to find 1/4 part of sum
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    sum[i] = a + a *(a/8); // Using arithmetic sequence formula to find 1/4 part of sum
}
```

or respectively

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sum[i] = a + a * (a/8); // Using arithmetic sequence formula to find 1/4 part of sum
}
```

---

Also you´re using `free(arg);` but it makes no sense to do so.

`arg` points to no memory need to be freed - allocated by a previous call to a memory-management function.